# Jpa/hibernate why detached entity merged partially?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, persistence

When i fetch entity from entity manager then make it detached and trying to delete related entities there is no changes in database to them. In other words after entity manager is closed (that is required) and opened again only changes to name field is merged but not for list of B. There is no exception or other errors or warnings. Hibernate log only shows select but not deletion from b_a database table.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = getAByIdFromRepository(2);
        B b = a.getB().stream().filter(i -> i.getId() == 1).findFirst().orElse(null);
        a.remove(b);
        repositoryMerge(a);
    }

    public static A getAByIdFromRepository(int id) {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence_unit");
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
        A a = em.find(A.class, id);
        em.close();
        factory.close();
        return a;
    }

    public static void repositoryMerge(A a) {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence_unit");
        EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.merge(a);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager.close();
        factory.close();
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
public class A implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "a_id")
    protected int id;
    @Column(name = "a_name")
    protected String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "a", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    protected List<B> b;

   //getters setters etc.

    public void remove(B b) {
        this.getB().remove(b);
        b.getA().remove(this);
    }

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "b")
public class B implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "b_id")
    protected int id;
    @Column(name = "b_name")
    protected String name;
    @JoinTable(
            name = "b_a",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "b_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "a_id"))
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    protected List<A> a;

  //getters setters etc.


}
```

And when fetching, deletion from entity and merging happens with one opened entity manager this is works:

```
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence_unit");
        EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
        A a = entityManager.find(A.class, 2);
        B b = a.getB().stream().filter(i -> i.getId() == 1).findFirst().orElse(null);
        a.remove(b);
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.merge(a);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager.close();
        factory.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Entity 'A' doesn't own the A.b ManyToMany relationship mapping since you've marked it as mappedBy the B.a relationship. This means that changes are only picked up from the B side of things - if you need to remove a 'B' instance from the relationship, you'll need to merge B into the context. You should still merge A if possible to keep the cached copy of A in synch with the database in various caching strategies, but isn't likely to be needed in the simple test you've shown.

There are a few ways to handle this, such as changing the owner of the relationship (akin to making it a unidirectional relationship from A->B), but I'd suggest instead just handling changes to the list of Bs yourself:

```
public static void repositoryMerge(A a) {
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence_unit");
    EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    final A managedA = entityManager.find(A.class, a.getId());
    List<B> missingBs = managedA.getB().stream().filter(
      b -> !a.getB().stream().anyMatch( 
        b1 -> Object.equals(b1.getId(), b.getId())));
    missingBs.stream().forEach(b-> b.getA().remove(managedA));
    entityManager.merge(a);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    entityManager.close();
    factory.close();
}
```

Comment: So why this is works with one opened entity manager? (question is updated) In working example there is no need to merge B, only A. I need a separate repository for A and B, in repository A find item by id, change fields, add or delete items from list of B's in A instance. Same with B repository. On the other hand i need to open and close entity manager for each operation for save, find and so on. Why hibernate doesn't figure out how to deal with list of related entities in detached entity?

Comment: When you read from one context and merge into another, It will only see the A' you give it, not the B' you've removed from B - it doesn't see that you've changed the B that has been dereferenced from A'. When you read in from a context, everything read in is managed within it. So that context (EntityManager) is aware of all changes you make to the A and B instances read in through it; merge(a) is completely unnecessary as the EntityManager will pick up any and all changes made to A and B

Comment: So how to delete from the non owning side? when i doing the same as in my not working  example but from owning side this works (fetch b with id 1 and delete a with id 2 from it). I need only deletion from b_a  table. How to do it in the correct way?

Comment: Don't just de-reference b, you have to merge it into the context as well.